# fminsearch with vector inputs

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, fminsearch

I want to minimize this function:

```
function [GCV2]=GCV(y,x,k)

[n, p]=size(x);

A=(x'*x+k*eye(p));
A=A\x';
A=x*A;

I_mat=eye(n);

num2=(I_mat-A);
num2=num2*y;
num2=norm(num2);
num2=num2^2;
num2=num2/n;

%(norm((I_mat-A)*y)^2)/n;
den2=(I_mat-A);
den2=trace(den2);
den2=den2/n;
den2=den2^2;

GCV2=num2/den2;

end
```

The `x` and `y` values are 13-by-4) and 13-by-1 arrays, respectively, and these values are already defined in the Matlab workspace. I want to optimize on the `k` value so that the function value `GCV` is minimized.

The parameter being optimized as well as the output are scalar so `fminsearch` should be appropriate.

But I can't get it to run?

I've tried several methods, the latest being:

```
k_min = fminsearch(@GCV,(x;y;0));
??? k_min = fminsearch(@GCV,(x;y;0));
                              |
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're learning about [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). `fminsearch` minimizes a single variable (which may be a vector). Your objective function must therefore have only one input. You have a function, `GCV`, that takes three inputs. Two are static and are defined in the workspace outside of the minimization, while `k` is the one to be minimized. To create a function with one input from `GCV`, you can use any anonymous function, taking care to specify which variables are parameters:

```
x = ...
y = ...
k0 = 0;
k_min = fminsearch(@(k)GCV(y,x,k),k0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second input to [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) is the starting parameter (i.e. `k0`), so specify a starting value of `k`.  Then you can define an anonymous helper function and optimize on that:

```
>> % define x,y
>> GCVk = @(k) GCV(y,x,k);
>> k0 = 0;
>> k_min = fminsearch(GCVk,k0)
```

There is probably another way to do this, but this is one of the listed ways of [passing additional parameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) for the optimizer.

And since there are no bonus points for being first, how about humor.  Let's have an example:

```
>> x=1; y=1;
>> GCVk = @(k) x+y+k; k0=0;
>> k_min = fminsearch(GCVk,k0)

Exiting: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded
         - increase MaxFunEvals option.
         Current function value: -316912650057057490000000000.000000 

k_min =
  -3.1691e+26
```

Found it - the lowest number (minus 2) in the world! Profit?